# How to create images with text when embedding word documents into one single document

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, embedding

I am using System.IO.Packaging and Open XML SDK to create a new docx. In my docx I want to embed other existing docx files. The result should be the same as I would do it manual in Microsoft Word. There should be an icon in the docx for each embedded docx file. In the icon I want to add the name of the embedded docx file. For all files to embed I have the same image. But I don't know how to add some text to the the image while embedding.

This is my code so far:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
{
  const string containingDocumentPath = @"ContainingDocument.docx";

  const string embeddedDocumentPath = @"EmbeddedDocument.docx";

  CreatePackage(containingDocumentPath, embeddedDocumentPath);
}

private static void CreatePackage(string containingDocumentPath, string embeddedDocumentPath)
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(containingDocumentPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
  {
    AddParts(package, embeddedDocumentPath);
  }
}

private static void AddParts(WordprocessingDocument parent,
                             string embeddedDocumentPath)
{
  var mainDocumentPart = parent.AddMainDocumentPart();
  GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainDocumentPart);

  var embeddedPackagePart =
    mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>(
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-" +
      "officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "rId1");

  GenerateEmbeddedPackagePart(embeddedPackagePart, embeddedDocumentPath);

  var imagePart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/x-emf", "rId2");
  GenerateImagePart(imagePart);
}

private static Document GenerateMainDocumentPart()
{
  var element =
    new Document(
      new Body(
        new Paragraph(
          new Run(
            new EmbeddedObject(
              new Shape(
                new ImageData()
                  {
                    RelationshipId = "rId2",
                  }
                )
                {
                  Id = "_x0000_i1025",
                  OptionalString = "abc",
                  Style = "width:16pt;height:16pt",
                },
              new OleObject()
                {
                  ProgId = "Word.Document.12",
                  ShapeId = "_x0000_i1025",
                  ObjectId = "_1299573545",
                  Id = "rId1"
                }
              )
              {
                DxaOriginal = "1531UL",
                DyaOriginal = "991UL"
              }
            )
          )
        )
      );

  return element;
}

public static void GenerateEmbeddedPackagePart(OpenXmlPart part, string embeddedDocumentPath)
{
  byte[] embeddedDocumentBytes;

  // The following code will generate an exception if an invalid
  // filename is passed.
  using (FileStream fsEmbeddedDocument = File.OpenRead(embeddedDocumentPath))
  {
    embeddedDocumentBytes = new byte[fsEmbeddedDocument.Length];

    fsEmbeddedDocument.Read(embeddedDocumentBytes, 0, embeddedDocumentBytes.Length);
  }

  using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(part.GetStream()))
  {
    writer.Write(embeddedDocumentBytes);
    writer.Flush();
  }
}

public static void GenerateImagePart(OpenXmlPart part)
{
  using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(part.GetStream()))
  {
    writer.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(@"Icons\MyImage.GIF"));
    writer.Flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use power tools for openxml? It has a simple method for combining two or more docx file into one. https://powertools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void GenerateEmbeddedIconPart(OpenXmlPart part, string filePath)
    {
        Byte[] image = GetIconBytes(filePath);
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(part.GetStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(image);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static Byte[] GetIconBytes(string filePath)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(150, 60);
        bitmap.MakeTransparent();
        System.Drawing.Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
        System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush drawBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

        string drawText = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
        graphics.DrawIcon(icon, 20, 0);
        graphics.DrawString(drawText, drawFont, drawBrush, 0, 48);                      

        Byte[] data;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        drawFont.Dispose();
        drawBrush.Dispose();
        graphics.Dispose();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.